# Is there a way to pass a ServletRequest parameter to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, servlets

Is there any way to pass the value  of a parameter from a **Servlet**  to **JavaScript** ?
the following didn't work.

```
var val = req.getParameter('valid');
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because the `ServletRequest` only exists at the server and your JavaScript is running at the browser. It is easy to get the difference confused, because the code that runs on the server and the code that runs in the browser are very often both written in the same file (`someServlet.java` or `somePage.jsp`), so you have to remember how everything will sit at runtime.

What you *can* do, as a way of passing information that is retrieved from the `request` in the `servlet` to the JavaScript, is embed the data in the structure of the page on the server side. The page and its structure are then passed to the browser and the JavaScript has access to the full page structure on the client side. So you put something like this in the `servlet`:

```
<form name="data" action="" >
    <input type="hidden" id="parmEmpId"
        value='<%= request.getParameter( "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" ) %>' />

    <input type="hidden" id="parmServerName"
        value="<%= request.getServerName() %>" />
</form>
```

And then, in your JavaScript, you can pull the data from the page:

```
var employeeId = $("#parmEmpId").val();    //Using jQuery
var server = $("#parmServerName").val();   //Using jQuery
```